# Firefox sidebar calling javascript functions in main browser window

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, sidebar

I'm trying to put together a quick Firefox sidebar for internal use only.

I'm struggling a bit in understanding how sidebar and main browser window communicate. What I want to do exactly is call existing javascript functions that reside in the main browser window only.

My code looks like this;

ff-sidebar.xul

```
<checkbox label="Button hover" checked="false" oncommand="add_enhance(this)"/>
```

ff-sidebar.js

```
function add_enhance(cb){
    if (cb.checked) {
        // this bit is wrong I know
        window.content.document.NEWSTYLE.buttonHover();
    }
}
```

So the question is, how do I call a function called `NEWSTYLE.buttonHover()` that lives in the main window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, this should work:

```
window.content.NEWSTYLE.buttonHover();
```

window.content points to the browser content window and the variable NEWSTYLE is defined on this window. In reality things are a bit more messy due to security mechanisms - privileged code cannot access objects of unprivileged code directly. Instead you get to access them through XPCNativeWrapper (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper). Technical details changed somewhat in Firefox 4 but essentially it is still the same.

The easiest way to do what you want without introducing security issues is changing the location of the content window to a javascript: URL. Like this:

```
window.content.location.href = "javascript:void NEWSTYLE.buttonHover()";
```

You won't be able to get the result of this function but it doesn't look like you need it.

Comment: Wladimir, thanks very much for that neat 'shortcut' using location.href. I have tried multiple variants of the `window.content` type but with no luck. The documentation is confusing. You are quite right in that I don't need a return from the function, in this case it is to trigger existing functions that add enhancements to show case on an internal site. I've been pulling my hair out over this one, so many thanks again for your answer!